# how to stop screen moving on ipad

Tags: ios, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an ASP MVC 3 application which I can access from an Ipad. I want the screen to be fixed while connected to this application from an ipad.

Does anyone know how to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved my problem but I Don't know if it's the right way to do it

```
<body id="content_body" ontouchmove="blockMove()">
  @* the body goes here *@
</body>
```

And here is the definition of javascript function

```
function blockMove() {
  event.preventDefault();
}
```